# Marker not working properly in ARtoolkit in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, artoolkit

I am working on a simple AR project using Unity and ARToolkit. For testing purposes, I have created a test project to track the image and create a simple 3d sphere and it is working perfectly when I play it from inside the Unity editor. The problem is that when I create the build .exe of the project, the application does not augment the 3D model of the marker when I put the marker in front of Camera (it should work as it is working when playing from inside the editor). It is also showing two errors as I build the project. Note that I have included the .dll files in the folder where .exe file is located. [image: Unity Editor]

[image]

Also I see that after building the project, the UID of the marker disappears as well as it is showing perfectly when played from inside the Unity Editor.
[image]

Kindly guide me in this matter as I have to submit this project to the university final year project. ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

several things on this:

- the disappearing of the marker ID during the build of the APP is normal and does not affect your result
- Please check if you have selected the correct scene when building your APP:

[Build view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wibYE.png)

select the "Add open scenes" button and tick the scene(s) you would like to include in your APP.

(It happens quite often that the wrong scene is picked)

- Also ensure that you are copying the correct versions of the dlls (32bit vs. 64bit) but if you copied the ones from the [appname]_data/Plugins directory you should be fine.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I have also copied the dlls from the [appname]_data/plugins directory to the directory where .exe of tbe project is located. And the project only contains a single scene which I am trying to build

Comment: Did you try what I said? Checking the 'Add open scenes' button might help if you had opened an other scene in the same project.

Comment: yes, it is working I have done what you said by Add Open Scene. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: can you please help me in another matter now that how can I use multiple NFT markers in my project. Kindly help on this issue.

Comment: Sure just drag and drop another ARMarker script to the ARToolKit object and configure it as NFT marker (the same as the other marker). Then create another Marker scene underneath Screen root and you should be good to go.

Please mark the answer as helpful. If you need more background about multiple NFTs please write a new question.