# ARToolkit application deployment on WIndows

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm trying to use ARToolkit and Unity to create a standalone Windows application. I'm able to let it work in Unity editor following instructions on ARToolkit official website.

When I click on Build Settings -> Build for Windows platform I obtain the .exe file but when I try to launch it I see the content of the camera but it seems not to be able to detect the marker.

Is there any particular setting to allow recignition of marker in a deployed Windows application?

I'm afraid that it's not able to find the marker specs. How can I debug if the marker recognition is working correctly? (e.g. adding some log code).

I've already checked to have selected the correct scene as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714066/marker-not-working-properly-in-artoolkit-in-unity).

I've also tried the ARToolkit base example without success.

During the building process an error regarding vcredist.exe appears (shown below) but I've already installed vcredist for Visual Studio 2013 and I don't think it's related to the problem because the camera opens correctly.

```
FileNotFoundException: ../Desktop/test/test_Data/Plugins/vcredist.exe does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this manner:

- changing the scene used for deployment as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714066/marker-not-working-properly-in-artoolkit-in-unity);
- deleting old generated Unity project;
- rebuilding project.

Previously I was building in the same directory the .exe and, probably, there was something that was not updated correctly.